# "Cannot iterate over null" when using jq to extract google speech-to-text transcript data from json file

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, jq, speech-to-text, google-speech-to-text-api

I'm trying to extract all the "transcript" data from this file which is the result of a Google Speech-to-Text request : https://pastebin.com/MFF1Dav8 (Not sensitive data, just from an interview I conducted).

To do so I found a prewritten command which I'm using :

```
jq <interview.json '.response.results[].alternatives[].transcript' -r > interview.txt
```

Except I get :

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:111181): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

How can I work around this ? All I want is the raw transcript text.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you posted does not have a top-level "response" key.

This seems to do the trick:

```
.results[].alternatives[].transcript
```